# Metric entropy: Question to partition if $N\to\infty$

Tags: measure-theory, entropy

I have a question concerning [this Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure-preserving_dynamical_system#Measure-theoretic_entropy) on metric entropy.

There, the following object is defined:
$$
\bigvee_{n=0}^NT^{-n}Q=\{Q_{i_0}\cap T^{-1}Q_{i_1}\cap\ldots\cap T^{-N}Q_{i_n}: \textrm{where }i_l=1,\ldots,k, l=0,\ldots,N\}
$$
and each element has *positive measure*.

I am wondering if this is also defined if $N\to\infty$ and how it looks like: Does all elements still have positive measure for $N\to\infty$? In other words, what is
$$
\bigvee_{n=0}^{\infty}T^{-n}Q?
$$

EDIT: I think $\bigvee_{n=0}^{\infty}T^{-n}Q$ is usually defined to be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra which contains $\bigvee_{n=0}^N T^{-n}Q$ for each $N\in\mathbb{N}$ (see, for example, [here, Definition 5](https://www.math.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/%7Elradu/files/e2.pdf)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, $\bigvee_{n=0}^{\infty}T^{-n}Q$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the elements of $\bigvee_{n=0}^NT^{-n}Q$ for all $N\in\mathbb N$.
It may happen **for example** that all elements of $\bigvee_{n=0}^{\infty}T^{-n}Q$ besides the empty set have positive measure or that only the empty set has zero measure. That depends on each measure and on each map.

For example, take $T(x)=2x\bmod1$ on $[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure. The Borel $\sigma$-algebra has the cardinality of $\mathbb R$ and so for example for $Q$ composed of $[0,\frac12]$ and $[\frac12,1]$ it is impossible that the sets in $\bigvee_{n=0}^NT^{-n}Q$ for all $N\in\mathbb N$ contain all the elements of the $\sigma$-algebra.

Two corrections on your post: you need to erase $l=0,\ldots,N$ in the definition of  $\bigvee_{n=0}^NT^{-n}Q$ and it is false in general that all the sets in $\bigvee_{n=0}^NT^{-n}Q$ have positive measure (note that in fact some may even be empty).

Comment: No, I didn't say that. I only gave examples of what can happen. I now clarified my answer.

Comment: You need to decide what version you take. Yours or the one in the link? My answer is, of course, for your definition. But both are completely fine and are used regularly in the theory since nothing changes (in the definition of entropy), although the answer depends on that.

Comment: Please clarify you question before anything else, writing things very clearly. I have already replied to what you have asked, in detail. If you believe that your question is clear, please ask another one, separately.